# How to push on GitHub from Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github, git-extensions

I have installed GitExtensions and Git Source Control Provider Options.
But after committing whenever I am trying to push something to the repository. Nothing is getting pushed.

What is happening? I am not well-versed with Git. Any help would be great.

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Are you asked for authentication? can you push from command-line?

Comment: My authentication is given on the Git's actual application for windows. So, no authentication is asked here.

Comment: OK, but unfortunately the authentication you gave to GitHub's desktop application isn't shared by Git's visual studio extension, they are independant software pieces

Comment: Okay. But where to update that credential? It has been not asked also.

Comment: That's why you have to install that piece of software, the windows credential store (link in my answer). It will (as I understand) add a layer that will ask for authentication during push

Comment: Okay. Let me check then. Thanks.

Comment: hey, did you sort it out?

Comment: No. Even GitExtension alone cannot push. Comes with same error that has been shown here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GitExtensions [doesn't work quite well with HTTPS authentication](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/85). This authentication problem makes the push fails, since the remote doesn't recognize you and thus rejects the push.

I haven't verified by myself, but with recent Git versions you can use the [Windows Credential Store for Git](https://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/). This will allow to authenticate against Github's remote during the push.

GitHub [mentions it in the documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git#platform-windows).

Comment: Is it an authentication problem? Or am I missing some procedure in Git?

Comment: Sorry. the problem persists. I've given my credential but that couldn't solve the problem. same window with same message appears.

Comment: Did you try the plugin solution. Can you try with command-line?

Answer (score 0):

OK, there's a simpler solution to let authentication work correctly with GitHub without using the Windows Credential Store.

You can use the GitExtensions' GitHub plugin, which use OAuth token by connecting to GitHub.

In GitExtensions, go to Plugin menu -> Github. It opens a browser window, which lets you authenticate and give authorization to GitExtension. After this no password prompting!

Comment: Yeah! I've tried this. But it's happening. I think I should use subversion instead!

Comment: That's strange; have you tried to push directly from GitExtensions?

Comment: I guess I am missing some trivial thing. Nothing is getting pushed from gitExtension also.

Comment: can you try with a `.git` extension at the end of the URL? Use the "manage remotes" in the remotes menu from GitExtensions

Comment: Yeah! I realized that and I tried with .git extension as well. But I couldn't figure what I should do with Manage Remotes there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34144/discussion-between-charlesb-and-soham-m17)